# checking whether the C compiler works... no when installing python 2.6 (mac os x lion)

Tags: c, xcode4, osx-lion, python-2.6

I'm trying to install python 2.6 using `pyenv` but when doing `pyenv install 2.6.9`I get the following:

```
checking MACHDEP... darwin
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... $(PLATMACDIRS)
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/r9/771hsm9931sd81ppz31384p80000gn/T/python-build.20150213191018.2121/Python-2.6.9':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I've installed Xcode 4.6.3 and installed Command Line Tools as info.

Cheers,

Ch

Comment: Show the contents of config.log.

Comment: Autoconf `configure` scripts output a log that provides details about the run, including any errors that occur.  Check that log to find out what command failed, with what error message.

Comment: This is part of my configure file:configure: `gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files` and also `ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5`

Comment: to complete the above: `ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3436: $? = 1
configure:3474: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the problem. The problem was with the `ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5`
The gcc version given by Xcode 4.6.3 on Mac OS X Lion is 4.6.

1. I installed the new gcc via homebrew, `brew install gcc`.
2. I symlink my gcc to gcc-4.9 by doing `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`.
3. make sure the that in your PATH `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` ).
4. To a `ls -l 'which gcc'` to check that gcc is associated to the 4.9 version. Once this is done, the library is found and python 2.6 can be installed using pyenv.